# Select query with where statement like %A30% result in %A30%, %A 30%, %A3 0%

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider I have the following table

| ID | model | sub_model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxxxxx | A 3052 |
| 2 | xxxxxx | A 3053 |
| 3 | xxxxxx | A 3054 |
| 4 | xxxxxx | A3055 |
| 5 | xxxxxx | A3 0BC |
| 6 | xxxxxx | A30 CD |

In my search function, I have an input bar to filter sub_model column. Current query will yield the result below.
Filter string: A30
Result :

| ID | model | sub_model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | xxxxxx | A3055 |

But the result I want is to show all the data(ID 1 - 6)
Where the where statement will search with any possible filter's space variant

Eg: A30 -> A 30, A3 0
Eg: A305 -> A 305, A3 05, A30 5

Is it possible to do that in SQL?

My current where SQL statement is

```
select * from [table] where sub_model like '%@filter%'
```

Comment: just remove the whitespace `select * from [table] where replace(sub_model, ' ', '') like '%@filter%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is string for set any variable you need do like

```
select * from [table] 
where replace(sub_model, ' ', '') -- from Ed Bangga Comment
  like concat('%',@filter,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the spaces of sub_model and then compare with your like condition in that way it will work.

```
select * from [table] where replace(sub_model,' ','') like  '%A30%';
```